# How can I maintain a reference to a set of defaults

Tags: design, database

I'm currently trying to better design a database structure for defaults where a reference to preset defaults is maintained globally, but the system is flexible enough to allow for new defaults to be added.

Database:

```
Default Fruits
----------------------------
ID:    Name:       Colour:
----------------------------
1      Apples      Green
2      Oranges     Orange
3      Bananas     Yellow



User Fruits
---------------------------------------------
UserID:    DefaultID       Name       Colour
---------------------------------------------
10         1 
10         NULL            Plums      Purple
10         2
```

User 10 would in this scenario be generating a dropdown of Apples, Plums and Oranges.

With the above database structure, my problem is that I need to be able to change the colour of an Apple to Black for a particular user but not change it globally. If I auto add the defaults for each user into user fruits, then I could potentially be left with orphan records. Is there a better DB design approach to consider for this scenario or does the above seem sensible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `User Fruits` table is not pretty. It's redundant to hold information about fruits in two separate places.

If you can change the fruit defaults on a per user basis, it would be better if you just had a `Fruits` table and a `User` table, and in the `Fruits` table you had a foreign key to the `User` table.

**Fruit Table**

```
| ID | Name  | Color | UserID |
| 1  | Apple | Green | 10     |
| 2  | Pear  | Brown | 10     |
```

This way, you can modify a fruit for one user without affecting the rest. Maybe you could make a stored procedure (or an application method) that populated the `Fruits` table with defaults for a user when you insert a new record (or whenever the appropriate time is).

Comment: Yes, but imagine for a moment that a new global default gets added or removed. This would involve sql to add or delete across all users, rather than a scenario where  a single record gets added to a global. Not sure if there is a work around for that scenario.

Comment: I do see your point @Paul. The fact that a default can change on a per user basis makes this difficult to implement cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

The design seems right. You won't be left with orphans if you add a foreign key constraint to delete refering rows on delete in the parent.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.User
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_T1_T2_Cascade
   FOREIGN KEY (DefaultID) REFERENCES dbo.Fruits(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
```